# How to access a file if user inputs the file path and do arithmetic operations on content of file?

Tags: c, file-handling, dynamic-arrays

I am in trouble opening the file, and don't know why it is not working.

Say if you have a file named `add.txt` and contents are 23 and 54 the program will take file path from you and then opens it and adds these two numbers.

It was working for me until i worked on integers only in my file. but i am not able to parse the file path here. Here is my code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0,j,k=0,l,sum=0;
    char a[200];
    char *ptr;
    int b[20];
    b[0]=0;
    char c[200];

fgets(c,sizeof(c),stdin);

j=strlen(c);

ptr=(char*)malloc(j*sizeof(char));
if(ptr==NULL)
{
    printf("insufficient space");
    exit(1);
}
for(l=0;l<=j;l++)
{
    *(ptr+l)=c[l];
}
printf("%s",ptr);
FILE *f;
f=fopen("ptr","r");
while(!feof(f))
{
    fscanf(f,"%c",&a[i]);
    i++;
}
for(l=0;l<i-1;l++)
{
    if(a[l]>=48&&a[l]<=57)
        b[k]=b[k]*10+a[l]-'0';
    else if(a[l]==10)
    {
        k++;
        b[k]=0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("invalid input");
        return 0;
    }
}
for(k=0;b[k]!='\0';k++)
{
    sum=sum+b[k];
}
printf("%d",sum);
free(ptr);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: You're passing a string literal `"ptr"` to `fopen()`, not the char pointer *ptr*. I think you also write 1 past the end of the buffer pointed to by *ptr*, aka you have UB.

Comment: i am passing the ptr, and ptr holds the string of c. so it should be the file name.

Comment: `for(l=0;l<=j;l++)`→`for(l=0;l<j;l++)`, `while(!feof(f))
{
    fscanf(f,"%c",&a[i]);` → `while(i < 200 && fscanf(f,"%c",&a[i]) == 1)
{`, And check if `fopen` was successful. Also, make sure the indices (`k`, `i` etc) don't go beyond the limit

Comment: It might be operating system specific, if you question is what happens when the contents of a file is changed while some program is reading it.

Comment: `f=fopen("ptr", "r")`  in your example passes a string literal as path. If it doesn't match your actual code, then please edit.

Answer (score 1):

I have refactored and updated your code
in the future avoid using a loop character letter l ('el') because it looks like a 1 (one)

Also try to use meaningful names for your variables it makes it much easier to understand the
code.

I have commented areas where problems where found.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
   int i=0,readCharactersLength,k=0,p,sum=0;
   int inFileNumbers[200]; //changed this from char to int since you are expecting numbers
   char *ptr;
   char readCharacters[200];

   fgets(readCharacters,sizeof(readCharacters),stdin);

   readCharactersLength= strlen(readCharacters);

   ptr=(char*)malloc(readCharactersLength*sizeof(char));

   if(ptr==NULL)
   {
      printf("insufficient space");
      exit(1);
   }

   for(p=0;p<=readCharactersLength;p++)
   {
      if(readCharacters[p] == '\n') //If at the end of the line exit and avoid assigning '\n'. This prevents errors when passing the pointer to the File to open
      break;

      *(ptr+p)=readCharacters[p];
   }

   printf("%s", ptr);

   FILE *f;

   f=fopen(ptr,"r");

   while(!feof(f))
   {
      fscanf(f,"%d",&inFileNumbers[i]);
      i++;
   }

   //You can add exception handling code here to handle invalid numbers/input
   //....

  for(k=0;k < i;k++)         //simply add all the numbers found
  {
     sum=sum+inFileNumbers[k];
  }

  printf("\n %d",sum);
  free(ptr);

  return 0;}
```

Happy coding and I hope it helps.